# How to get any published facebook page information using graph api in php?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get some public information of a facebook page (total likes, total Posts, total comments, website, last post time etc). So i have integrate facebook php sdk, and i create an app. now the problem is when i am trying to get those information it says user need to give the permission. But i need to keep the user anonymous, so that visitor can come and send the page link and will get data to my webpage.

So my question is: do i really need a user for this? i think access token will generate based on my fb-app. and if this is the case please help me to find out what i did wrong here.

Here is my code

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'app_secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
        ]);

    $helper = $fb->getPageTabHelper();
    try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
    if (! isset($accessToken)) {
        echo 'No OAuth data could be obtained from the signed request. User has not authorized your app yet.';
        exit;
    }
    echo '<h3>Page ID</h3>';
    var_dump($helper->getPageId());

    echo '<h3>User is admin of page</h3>';
    var_dump($helper->isAdmin());
```

and the response is `No OAuth data could be obtained from the signed request. User has not authorized your app yet.`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure how you would detect if the user is admin of the page, without authorization? either way, you can use an app access token for unrestricted pages and a user or page token for restricted pages (by age or location). the best thing to do is authorize users with manage_pages, and let him choose one of the pages he manages. that way, you can even get access to the page insights.

Comment: btw, the pagetabhelper is for page tabs...are you using a page tab or just a simple external website?

Comment: more information about tokens (including the official docs link): http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: @luschn Actually i do not need to detect is if the user is admin or not, i only need the public information of a page which are open for anyone, to do so i need access token which i am trying to get here. Can you please tell me that how i'll be able to get app access token? i am using this code in my website to get only some information of a page, Actually i found facebook documentation not understandable, so i need a code example.

Comment: open the link i commented, there is all the info you need about all access tokens. app tokens are easy to generate, you do not need any api call for them.

Comment: that's not helping, i need a real example.

Answer (score 0):

For unrestricted Pages, you can just use an App Access Token. The FacebookRequest class offers a method to set the Access Token: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRequest/ (`setAccessToken`)

The App Access Token is easy to generate, it is just the App ID and the App Secret, combined with a pipe sign: `App-ID|App-Secret`

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: thanks, but still not working. It says `Fatal error: Call to a member function getClient() on null`. And the second link says `https://graph.facebook.com/endpoint?key=value&amp;access_token=app_id|app_secret` would make the call, but it returns a error `(#803) Cannot query users by their username (endpoint)`

Comment: what are you trying to do? are we really talkin about PAGES and not USER PROFILES? what is "endpoint" exactly in your call? can you post a real example? (without a real app token, of course)

Comment: about the first error: make sure you initialize the facebook app correctly in the php sdk. debug $fb.